# When can I access the data of my NSDocument during the initialization?

Tags: macos, cocoa, initialization, nsdocument

I need to instantiate some properties with the content of the saved document. Since theses properties are used by my interface, I would like to instantiate them before the NIB is loaded.

At which point of my initialization can I access the data of the loaded document ?

If possible, I would like to access it not from the `initFromURL` method. Indeed, when I create a document, I also create this data. So, if it is possible, I would like to put the instanciation at only one point, that will work for both the creation and the opening of a document.

So, is there an accessible point after the `initFromURL` and `initWithType` methods but before the `windowControllerDidLoadNib`.

Thanks !

Comment: How about `windowControllerWillLoadNib`

Comment: Yes, that sounds perfect. I think I will still have an issue, in the case of an autosaved document... Let me check !

Comment: The method `windowControllerWillLoadNib` is also called in the case of autosaved documents! Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy !

```
-windowControllerWillLoadNib
```